# How to ensure spark not read same data twice from cassandra

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax

I'm learning spark and cassandra. My problem is as follows. 
I have cassandra table which records row data from a sensor

```
CREATE TABLE statistics.sensor_row (
    name text,
    date timestamp,
    value int,
    PRIMARY KEY (name, date)
)
```

Now I want to aggregate these rows through a spark batch job (ie. Daily)

So I could write

```
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("statistics","sensor_row")
//and do map and reduce to get what i want and perhaps write back to aggregated table.
```

But my problem is I will be running this code periodically. I need to make sure I dont read same data twice.

One thing I can do is delete rows which I read, which looks pretty ugly, or use filter

```
sensorRowRDD.where("date >'2016-02-05 07:32:23+0000'")
```

Second one looks much nicer, but then I need to record when was the job run last and continue from there. However according to DataStax driver data locality, each worker will load data only in its local cassandra node. Which mean instead of tracking a global date, i need to track date of each cassandra/spark node. Still does not look very elegant.

Is there any better ways of doing this ?

Comment: Why would you need 8 dates? One global value would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataFrame filters will be pushed down to Cassandra, so this is an efficient solution to the problem. But you are right to worry about the consistency issue.

One solution is to set not just a start date, but an end date also. When your job starts, it looks at the clock. It is `2016-02-05 12:00`. Perhaps you have a few minutes delay in collecting late-arriving data, and the clocks are not absolutely precise either. You decide to use 10 minutes of delay and set your end time to `2016-02-05 11:50`. You record this in a file/database. The end time of the previous run was `2016-02-04 11:48`. So your filter is `date > '2016-02-04 11:48' and date < '2016-02-05 11:50'`.

Because the date ranges cover all time, you will only miss events that have been saved into a past range after the range has been processed. You can increase the delay from 10 minutes if this happens too often.

Comment: Having upperbound to the filter make sense. However I guess i have to record last run time for each spark worker dont I (data locality). ?. That might lead to inconsistent states if node failed and re-routed to different host.

Comment: No, I think it is enough to record the end time, as a global setting. I don't know how failures are handled though. I would assume the Cassandra driver somehow takes care of this and ensures that all of the data is scanned, but perhaps not. I have no experience with Cassandra, just Spark. Let's hope someone with more Cassandra knowledge can confirm/deny this. If not, perhaps it's worth a separate question specifically about the failure handling.

Comment: I think you are correct about the driver taking care of the complexity. However there is only one way to find out. I would try to setup a multi-node cluster and do some testing.